# Scikit-learn's Ridge clasifier's working for multi-class not clear

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand how the `RidgeClassifier` from `sklearn.linear_model` works for Multi class case. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911663/what-does-sklearn-ridgeclassifier-do/53912015). However I am unable to follow

According to what I understand from the answer there.

```py
import numpy as np


X = np.random.random((5,4))
y =  [0,1,0,2,2]


############## This method #################

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
y_new  = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
r = Ridge()
r.fit(X,y_new)
r.coef_

############# is same as this ##############

from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
clf = RidgeClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.coef_
```

However the `coef_` is not same. What actually happens for the Multi class case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is totally right and you are in fact building the same output.

The `LabelBinarizer` is converting your class values (`1, 2, 3`) into a multi-output of binary values (`1, 0, 0`, `0, 1, 0`, `0, 0, 1`). Applying a `Ridge` regressor on this output will make your multi-class regression behave like a multi-class classification if you take the highest output for example.

The `RidgeClassifier` converts the class values between `-1` and `1`, because regression is **more performant when the output is symmetrical**. This is the main difference between the two approaches, with some sugar on top of it to improve performance and convergence.

Check the source of the `RidgeClassifier` : [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L769)

In the `fit` function, you will see the use of your `LabelBinarizer`, but with parameters to make it between `-1` and `1`.

Your final coefs are different, but it is normal because the raw output is different. However, if you take the maximum, you will normally get the same classification output.